# merge two lists in python - but sort them during merge

Tags: python, django

i am querying from two models:

```
fq = MyModel.objects.order_by('-added_time')
sq = MySecondModel.objects.order_by('-added_time')
```

say, querysets are:

```
1_1, 1_2, 1_3
2_1, 2_2, 2_3
```

I want:

```
1_1, 2_1, 1_2, 2_2, 1_3, 2_3
```

what I tried is:

```
all_res = list(fq) + list(sq)
```

but it is giving `1_1, 1_2, 1_3, 2_1, 2_2, 2_3`

what should i do to achieve what i want? I am using `paginator`, so the result should also be a queryset.

**EDIT**:

this is how i am doing now:

```
fq= MyModel.objects.order_by('-added_time')
sq = MySecondModel.objects.order_by('-added_time')
all_res = sorted(chain(fq, sq),key=attrgetter('-added_time'))
```

and i have this type of pagination, where i set the left and right side distance in pages.

[image]

this left and right distances i set as follows:

```
min = all_res.number - 5
max = all_res.number + 5
```

and this lines are giving me error: `'list' object has no attribute 'number'` since `all_res` is a list.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'number'` or `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'number'` when I try to call number on a queryset.

Comment: @BSpiros, of course, ``all_res`` should be paginator object i think, right?

Comment: I would think so. I haven't actually implemented anything with Paginator. The query (I would think) should be relatively far away from that. You know that you're returning the results of `myAwesomeQuery.filter(whatever="whatever")[n:n+len(pg)]`, so you know the value of n. You don't need anything from the query object since n gives you enough info to set the pages appropriately.

Comment: @BSpiros, ok thanks dude, i am a bit messed up right now.. i rererethink what i want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to sort them, or do you want to interlace them? If the former,

```
all_res = sorted(list(fq) + list(sq), key = lambda x: (x[-1], x[0]))
```

Comment: one more thing. it seems, i need queryset again as a result because i am using paginator. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Presumably the info to pick the page is in the query? Just use that to filter by throwing a slice on the end: `fq = MyModel.objects.order_by('-added_time')[page_start:page_finish]`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Comment: @BSpiros, i am doing in my view ``all_res.number`` and it is saying, ``'list' object has no attribute 'number'``

Comment: @doniyor, is this after you take a slice of it or are you using the list comprehension below? I just tried `>> type(User.objects.filter(email__contains="smith")[0:3])` and got `>> django.db.models.query.QuerySet`

Comment: @BSpiros, no i didnot take slice.. what i am trying to do is: i want to set min and max for pagination and for this, i am setting ``result.number-5`` and ``result.number+5`` respectively. and that result is now list and giving me error above

Comment: Can you please throw your queryset into a comment or edit so that I can get a better idea of what you're going for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [heapq's merge](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) (to merge multiple sorted iterables):

```
In [11]: a = [1, 4, 6]

In [12]: b = [2, 3, 7]

In [13]: list(heapq.merge(a, b))
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Existing code:

```
fq = MyModel.objects.order_by('-added_time')
sq = MySecondModel.objects.order_by('-added_time')

1_1, 1_2, 1_3
2_1, 2_2, 2_3
```

You want:

```
1_1, 2_1, 1_2, 2_2, 1_3, 2_3
```

If you know that the order you want is fq[n], sq[n], fq[n+1]... etc then the solution is pretty easy. If you don't know for sure that the objects will come out in that pattern (missing data?) then I would suggest just combining the lists and sorting after.

```
answer = [f for s in zip(fq, sq) for f in s]
```

Comment: thanks, but i need queryset again as a result after merging because i am using paginator

Comment: You don't need them as a queryset after since you can slice as a part of getting the query (see link in comments above). Just don't overwrite the queryset.